# Can you help me with this question about permutation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Example: A garden has 4 types of flowers: roses, lilies, tulips and sunflowers. Flowers of the same type are considered identical. In how many ways can we make a bouquet of 10 flowers, if we must have at least 2 roses and 1 tulip?

my answer: $$C(n+r-1,r)=C(4+7-1,7)=\frac{10!}{7!(10-7)!}=120$$ is it correct??

Comment: Assuming that order of flowers within the bouquet doesn't matter and there is no limit to the number of each flower type available, yes it looks fine.

Comment: yes, there are no limits on the numbers of each type of the flowers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your answer is correct. The answer also represents the number of solutions to the following equation-
$$r+l+t+s=7$$
where r, l, t, s is the number of roses,lilies, tulips and sunflowers respectively.